Connecting from Windows PowerShell to AWS Lightsail Ubuntu
My first exposure to running my system on AWS Lightsail, running Ubuntu 24.04. I generated a new Instance running Ubuntu 24.04 with a static IP. While generating the instance I also generated a new key pair option and downloaded the Private key file to my Win11 machine. I placed the file in C:\users\myname\tomcat.pem. Then I pointed the Powershell to this file with the ssh -i command followed by username@Static_IP however I'm not able to get in. :(
I get an error message Permission denied (publickey). [process exited with code 255 (0x000000ff)]
If I left out any details please let me know
TIA
Edit: Get-Acl output
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\users\myname\tomcat.pem
Owner  : MYPCNAME\myname
Group  : MYPCNAME\myname
Access : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         MYPCNAME\myname Allow  FullControl
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-896256906-3601579601-2063631356-1001G:S-1-5-21-896256906-3601579601-2063631356-1001D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;S
         Y)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-896256906-3601579601-2063631356-1001)


Use Get-Acl "C:\users\myname\tomcat.pem" | Format-List and lets see the permission on that pem file as it aught to be very restrictive before usage

Thank you George for your reply. The output lists MyMachine\myname as the Owner and Group. And in the Access section there are 3 entities. SYSTEM, Administrators and me.

Please we see the output, update your question

Done. Thank you.

as a security measure ssh will fail if ssh file has too loose permissions ... goal is to alter permissions on that file so your username has access and remove permissions from all else for this file ... you are now armed with what to do now just find out how

Now lets fix the permission state of the file with the following commands ```icacls "C:\users\myname\tomcat.pem" /inheritance:r
icacls "C:\users\myname\tomcat.pem" /grant:r "%username%:R"


Thank you George and Scott for your help. I ran both commands and I see that I'm the only one left with the access to this file, and only the read access. However, I still get the same error. :( It seems like something else is wrong.

Note for people who see this later on. %username% should be replaced with your actual username. :)
